Using Python to solve the "resistor cube"

This is a computational problem.
My code:
import numpy as np

# Number of nodes in the cube
num_nodes = 8

# Create the conductance matrix G and the current vector I
G = np.zeros((num_nodes, num_nodes))
I = np.zeros(num_nodes)

# Define resistances
R1 = 0.18  # Resistance for R1
R = 1      # Resistance for other resistors

# Function to add conductances between nodes i and j with resistance R
def add_conductance(G, i, j, R):
    conductance = 1 / R
    G[i, i] += conductance
    G[j, j] += conductance
    G[i, j] -= conductance
    G[j, i] -= conductance

# Define the connections for the cube (each edge of the cube)
edges = [
    (0, 1, R), (1, 2, R), (2, 3, R), (3, 0, R),  # Bottom face
    (4, 5, R), (5, 6, R), (6, 7, R), (7, 4, R),  # Top face
    (0, 4, R), (1, 5, R), (2, 6, R), (3, 7, R),  # Vertical edges
    (3, 4, R1)                                   # Special resistor R1
]

# Add conductances to the matrix G
for i, j, R_val in edges:
    add_conductance(G, i, j, R_val)

# Define the current injections (1A into node 0 and -1A out of node 7)
I[0] = 1   # Inject 1A at node 0 (node A)
I[7] = -1  # Extract 1A at node 7 (node B)

# To avoid singular matrix, we ground node 7 (remove last row and column from G and I)
G_reduced = np.delete(np.delete(G, 7, axis=0), 7, axis=1)
I_reduced = np.delete(I, 7)

# Solve for the node voltages
V_reduced = np.linalg.solve(G_reduced, I_reduced)

# Insert the ground node voltage back (V[7] = 0)
V = np.insert(V_reduced, 7, 0)

# Calculate the equivalent resistance as the voltage difference between nodes 0 and 7
R_eq = V[0] - V[7]

print(f"The equivalent resistance between A and B is {R_eq:.3f} ohms.")

However, the code gives the wrong values, which I can check.

Why do you have R1 = 0.18 when the question mentions 0.5?

(Also, please include the question text as normal text at least as well. The image text is badly readable with its light and small font.)

You define R1 to be (3, 4, R1). That seems to be a diagonal, in contrast to the image. Additionally, that results in a cube with 13 edges.

Further, you inject the current at node 0, which according to your cube definition is at the bottom face, but the picture shows it to be at the top. And vice versa for exit node 7, which in your definition is at the top, but the picture shows it to be at the bottom. With symmetry, this wouldn't be a problem, but the cube is not symmetric because of the presence of R1. Also, node 0 and node 7 are not opposite of each other, like they are in the picture.

What is the expected answer anyway? And what answer do you get currently?

I reckon the overall resistance is 0.7632 ohms. Any takers?

@9769953 Hi, I had R1=0.18 because i could actually test for different R1s to see if the code gives consistent right or wrong answers. And I wasn't to sure how to solve this problem (by hand) so I went on google to see some analysis, and my code basically is the numerical version of that analysis I found online, I think that's why things are inconsistent....As for expected answer, I cannot actually see. the expected answer I can only test if my answer is correct.

Once you have the voltages at the nodes you can back-check your answer. Current is voltage drop divided by resistance, then net current out of every junction is 0.

I have had a go at correcting your code. Your node numbers are inconsistent (as noted by user 9769953). I've put 0-3 on the top and 4-7 on the bottom. Current inlet at 0 and outlet at 6.
It looks a bit like this:
   I
===>=== 0----------3
       /.         /|
      / .        / |
     1----------2  |
     |  4 . . . |. 7
     | .        | /
     |.         |/    I
     5----------6 ===>===

Your setting up of R1 was wrong.
To ground one value (say V6) you DON'T have to remove that line: just change it to all zeros except a 1 on the diagonal and set the RHS to 0.
If R1=0.5 (as stated in the question, but not your code) you get the following.
import numpy as np

# Number of nodes in the cube
num_nodes = 8

# Create the conductance matrix G and the current vector I
G = np.zeros((num_nodes, num_nodes))
I = np.zeros(num_nodes)

# Define resistances
R1 = 0.5   # Resistance for R1                                    # <======= corrected
R = 1      # Resistance for other resistors

# Function to add conductances between nodes i and j with resistance R
def add_conductance(G, i, j, R):
    conductance = 1 / R
    G[i, i] += conductance
    G[j, j] += conductance
    G[i, j] -= conductance
    G[j, i] -= conductance

# Define the connections for the cube (each edge of the cube)
edges = [
          (0, 1, R), (1, 2, R), (2, 3, R), (3, 0, R1),     # Top face (corrected R1 and node numbers)
          (4, 5, R), (5, 6, R), (6, 7, R), (7, 4, R ),     # Bottom face (corrected node numbers to match current)
          (0, 4, R), (1, 5, R), (2, 6, R), (3, 7, R )      # Vertical edges
        ]

# Add conductances to the matrix G
for i, j, R_val in edges:
    add_conductance(G, i, j, R_val)

# Define the current injections (1A into node 0 and -1A out of node 6)
I[0] = 1   # Inject 1A at node 0 (node A)
I[6] = -1  # Extract 1A at node 6 (node B)       <====== Corrected

# To avoid singular matrix FORCE V[6] to be 0
G[6,:] = 0;   G[6,6] = 1.0;   I[6] = 0

# Solve for the node voltages
V = np.linalg.solve(G, I)

# Calculate the equivalent resistance as the voltage difference between nodes 0 and 6    # <==== Corrected
R_eq = V[0] - V[6]

print( "Conductance matrix:" )
print( G )
print( "\nVoltages:" )
print( V )
print(f"\nThe equivalent resistance between A and B is {R_eq:.3f} ohms.")

Output:
Conductance matrix:
[[ 4. -1.  0. -2. -1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  3. -1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  3. -1.  0.  0. -1.  0.]
 [-2.  0. -1.  4.  0.  0.  0. -1.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  3. -1.  0. -1.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0. -1.  3. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -1. -1.  0. -1.  3.]]

Voltages:
[ 7.63157895e-01  4.73684211e-01  3.42105263e-01  5.52631579e-01
  4.73684211e-01  3.15789474e-01 -9.32233669e-18  3.42105263e-01]

The equivalent resistance between A and B is 0.763 ohms.


Thank you so much....I didn't quite know how to even solve this by hand so I followed the analysis of some guy I found on the internet, I guess he used a different numbering system... i see where I went wrong now! Thank you
